# LED timer trigger Linux

Tags: linux

I am driving external LEDs on my development board. I am using the Linux 'timer' trigger to blink them. However, the trigger allows the blinking of LEDs at a fixed rate. Is it possible to configure the rate at which the LEDs blink using the 'timer' trigger?

Comment: which board you use? put your code here,>>"Is it possible to configure the rate at which the LEDs blink using the 'timer' trigger", yes if each LED connect to a pin you can send order to each one you loke to turn on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ledtrig-timer.c` should provide `delay_on` and `delay_off` device files for the LED which can be used to set how long the LED is on and how long the LED is off.

Setting both of them to a small value will result in a fast flash rate.
Setting both of them to a small value will result in a slow flash rate.

Setting one longer than the other will result in varying "on" and "off" durations.

The LED Kernel Timer Trigger file [ledtrig-timer.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/leds/ledtrig-timer.c?v=2.6.33) is well commented and should help you figure out how to control the LEDs.
*Note that the link is for an older 2.6 kernel, but it is better documented than the newer versions of the file.*